# Is there a way to detect whether a screen is in on/off/standby mode from within Linux?

Tags: monitoring, graphics, monitors, hdmi

The screen in question is HDMI. The power off/on action is initiated by clicking on the on-screen capacitive button.

I just need to know if there is a way to get events like "now the screen is on", "now the screen is off/unplugged", "now the screen is in standby mode".

If at all possible, I would like to avoid timer-based approaches and to rely to events (however, a timer-based approach is still better than having no clue).

Answer (score 5):

Try `xset q` to get [DPMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling) settings. Seems to say things like 'Monitor is On'

## References:

- [How can I put my HDMI display into (and out of) power save mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52263/how-can-i-put-my-hdmi-display-into-and-out-of-power-save-mode)
- https://systembash.com/how-to-turn-off-your-monitor-via-command-line-in-ubuntu/
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/vbetool
- https://superuser.com/questions/942468/xset-dpms-command-is-not-shutting-down-the-monitor - points at `vbetool` and `tvservice` for Raspberry Pi
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=16472&p=176258

Comment: That's unfortunately not working: I'm using Kodi through a framebuffer (RPi 2). I get `xset:  unable to open display ""`. Sorry for not specifying that before.

Comment: By the way, specifying `DISPLAY=0` or the like explicitly does not work either as Xorg is not even installed on the box. That said, Xorg gets its info from somewhere. If I knew what this "somewhere" was, that would work.

Comment: Ah. ARM.I'd take a look at tvservice, vbetool and setterm as well. Or strace that xset and see what syscalls it does. Or look at the source. See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling#DPMS_interaction_in_a_Linux_console_with_setterm

Comment: `tvservice`: that's how I can currently get the "screen turned on" event. `vbetool`: great hope, great disappointment (can just set DPMS, not read). `setterm`: same thing as `vbetool` but already disillusioned. :)

Comment: BTW, I've already read all that has been cited (and much more). But except `xset -q` which works only with X, there is absolutely *nothing* about getting this kind of events. Only answers to the same tired (and unrelated) question: "doh, how can I turn off my screen from SW?". But this is not what I want.

Comment: And before you recommend it, `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd display_power` does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

When I play a Youtube video it disables DPMS and then there is no "Monitor is on/off" line in the output of `xset q`.

Though it's not event-driven, this works even when DPMS is disabled -- if you're using X display manager and don't mind compiling a bit of C.

Name the the script "is_monitor_on.c" and compile with
command: `gcc ./is_monitor_on.c -o ./is_monitor_on -lX11 -lXss`

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    if (display == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open display\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int screen = DefaultScreen(display);

    XScreenSaverInfo *info = XScreenSaverAllocInfo();
    XScreenSaverQueryInfo(display, RootWindow(display, screen), info);

    if (info->state == ScreenSaverOn) {
        printf("Screen is off or locked.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Screen is on and not locked.\n");
    }

    XCloseDisplay(display);
    XFree(info);
}
```